# Periodicity of Sine from infinite Product Formula: $z\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions, infinite-product

Let $\sin z$ be **defined** by the following infinite product:

$$
\sin (z) = z \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2} \right)
$$

How can one derive that $\sin(z + 2\pi) = \sin(z)$?

Comment: See that$$1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}=\left(1-\frac z{n\pi}\right)\left(1+\frac z{n\pi}\right)$$and show that offsetting the resulting product does not affect the value it converges to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
&(z+2\pi) \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{(z+2\pi)^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)
\\\\=\:&(z+2\pi) \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{z+2\pi}{n\pi}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1+\frac{z+2\pi}{n\pi}\right)
\\\\=\:&(z+2\pi) \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{z}{n\pi}-\frac{2}{n}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1+\frac{z}{n\pi}+\frac{2}{n}\right)
\\\\=\:&(z+2\pi)\prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{2}{n\left(1-\frac{z}{n\pi} \right)}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n\left(1+\frac{z}{n\pi} \right)}\right)
\\\\=\:&(z+2\pi)\prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) \cdot\prod_{n=1}^{N} \frac{((n-2) \pi -z) ((n+2) \pi +z)}{(n \pi -z) (n \pi +z)}
\end{align}
$$ then factors telescope in the latter product giving
$$
\begin{align}
&(z+2\pi) \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{(z+2\pi)^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)
\\\\=\:&(z+2\pi)\cdot \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)\cdot \frac{z(\pi+N\pi +z) ((2+N)\pi+z)}{(z+2\pi)((N-1)\pi-z)(N\pi-z)}
\\\\=\:&z\cdot \prod_{n=1}^{N} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)\cdot \frac{(\pi+N\pi+z)((2+N)\pi+z)}{((N-1)\pi-z) (N\pi-z)}
\end{align}
$$ then letting $N \to \infty$ gives the desired identity.